# edit magic command in Spyder IDE

Tags: python, spyder

I am working with Spyder IDE. In console IPython I type

```
%edit myfile.csv
```

If my understanding is correct, this magic command should not open the file in
the Editor? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, that's right, but unfortunately this doesn't work on Windows at the moment. Are you using Windows?

Comment: @CarlosCordoba (Thanks first of all!). Yes (unfortunately:-)!). But I also work in Ubuntu. I guess there is no problem there. By the way when I open with windows shell and open an Ipython session there, typing above magic command works as desired. In fact, following the procedure described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15681153/external-editor-for-ipython-notebook I managed to change the default editor (notepad++ instead of notepad). But the problem is still with the Spyder IDE.

Comment: We redefine `%edit` in Spdyer to make it work in our IPython consoles, but I don't why it's failing on Windows. Could you open a bug report in our Github website so we don't forget to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: @CarlosCordoba. Ok. I will do like this. Congaturlations for the amazing environment you have created. The computer I face the problem is running Windows 7. I also have another computer with Windows 10 installed. I will chek what is going and I will inform you through this post.