# jupyter console and ipython

Tags: ipython, jupyter-console

In my conda environment, I installed both `jupyter` and `ipython`. The result for `conda list jupyter` and `conda list ipython` are as follows:

`jupyter_client            5.1.0                    py35_0    defaults
jupyter_console           5.2.0                    py35_0    defaults
jupyter_contrib_core      0.3.3                    py35_0    conda-forge
jupyter_contrib_nbextensions 0.3.1                    py35_0    conda-forge
jupyter_core              4.3.0                    py35_0    defaults
ipython                   6.1.0                    py35_0    defaults
ipython_genutils          0.1.0                    py35_0    defaults`

From web I found  that `jupyter` uses `ipython` kernel. Does not this mean that the `jupyter console` and `ipython` installed should be the same thing and should be configured at the same place?

I feel them are two completely independent things and one to be configured in `.jupyter` and one to be configured in `.ipython`.

Do I need to abandon `ipython` completely and use `jupyter` only?

---

One more question: to config `ipython`'s editor, I use the `EDITOR` environment variable and it is easy. To config `jupyter console`'s editor, the doc says

```
%edit runs an external text editor. You will need to set the command
for this editor via the ``TerminalInteractiveShell.editor`` option in 
your configuration file before it will work.
```

But where to set it? When I search the internet, all results point to `ipython` like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15681153/external-editor-for-ipython-notebook). Its really confusion.